# Python : pysvn.Client.info2() - when using this command, the list doesn't appear in alphabetical format

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I am trying to extract the file details using the below code:

```
client = pysvn.Client()
for i in PATH:
            temp1.append(client.info2(i,recurse=True))
```

where `PATH` is the location where I have exported files from SVN.

I have tried to list sort the file details per name of the files in aplhabetical order, in the temp1 list above. But it is not working. Any other way to get the info from a SVN repository, as it appears on the SVN will be helpful.

Comment: info2 returns the data exactly as the svn library code returns it. I do not think it is sorted. That is your responsibility. sort the list with somehting like sorted( client.info2(...) )